# The supplied file ExtentReports.html is not a valid Extent file. Parsing failed, tests from the supplied file will not be listed in the current report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am facing an issue with the ExtentReports.html file stating that it is not a valid Extent File.

TestNG's default listener is used to generate Extent Reports. As stated in other questions, I added `reports.flush()` in `onFinish(ITestContext context)` method which is executed after all the @Test methods.

This issue occurs in the line below:

```
public class TestListener implements ITestListener {

public ExtentReports reports;

public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
    /** this is where the error is thrown **/ 
    reports = new ExtentReports(dir + "/ExtentReportTestNG.html", false, DisplayOrder.OLDEST_FIRST);
    reports.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/extent-config.xml"));
    }
}
```

Actually I can say it is a severe warning:

```
SEVERE: The supplied file C:\Bala\E\Checkouts\seleniumScriptsRegression\test-output\ExtentReportTestNG.html is not a valid Extent file. Parsing failed, tests from the supplied file will not be listed in the current report.
```

This warning affects the below line of code:

```
public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
try {
        reports.endTest(test);
        reports.flush(); //The error line
    }
}
```

Below is the complete stack trace of a NullPointerException:

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> report.systemInfoMap[info]  [in template "Extent.ftl" at line 193, column 95]

----
Tip: It's the final [] step that caused this error, not those before it.
----
Tip: If the failing expression is known to be legally refer to something that's sometimes null or missing, either specify a default value like myOptionalVar!myDefault, or use <#if myOptionalVar??>when-present<#else>when-missing</#if>. (These only cover the last step of the expression; to cover the whole expression, use parenthesis: (myOptionalVar.foo)!myDefault, (myOptionalVar.foo)??
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${report.systemInfoMap[info]}  [in template "Extent.ftl" at line 193, column 93]
----

Java stack trace (for programmers):
----
freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: [... Exception message was already printed; see it above ...]
    at freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException.getInstance(InvalidReferenceException.java:131)
    at freemarker.core.EvalUtil.coerceModelToString(EvalUtil.java:355)
    at freemarker.core.Expression.evalAndCoerceToString(Expression.java:82)
    at freemarker.core.DollarVariable.accept(DollarVariable.java:41)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitByHiddingParent(Environment.java:345)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlockInner(IteratorBlock.java:240)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.executeNestedBlock(IteratorBlock.java:220)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock$IterationContext.accept(IteratorBlock.java:194)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visitIteratorBlock(Environment.java:572)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.acceptWithResult(IteratorBlock.java:78)
    at freemarker.core.IteratorBlock.accept(IteratorBlock.java:64)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:54)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:324)
    at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:302)
    at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:325)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.flush(HTMLReporter.java:173)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.flush(Report.java:468)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:900)
    at com.exterro.fusion.selenium.controls.TestListener.onFinish(TestListener.java:195)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1239)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1030)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:636)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.utils.Writer.write(Writer.java:21)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.HTMLReporter.flush(HTMLReporter.java:186)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.Report.flush(Report.java:468)
    at com.relevantcodes.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:900)
    at com.exterro.fusion.selenium.controls.TestListener.onFinish(TestListener.java:195)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.fireEvent(TestRunner.java:1239)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.afterRun(TestRunner.java:1030)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:636)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1244)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1064)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. And it got resolved by removing one of the null row in
ExtentReports report.ExtentReport.extent.addSystemInfo. See if you are adding any null value to the property value pair.